# Error using ASMifierClassVisitor

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation, java-bytecode-asm

I wanted to use ASMifierClassVisitor tool to get the asm code of creating a class but when I use it I get the error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Lorg/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor;[Lorg/objectweb/asm/Attribute;Z)V
        at org.objectweb.asm.util.ASMifierClassVisitor.main(Unknown Source)
```

I used the code

```
ASMifierClassVisitor.main(new String[]{testforloops.Equivalent.class.getName()});
```

what is the problem here?

Comment: Sounds like you've got several incompatible versions of ASM on your classpath.

Comment: what would be a possible solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the issue. I had asm-util-2.3 before asm-util-3.3 in my classpath when I removed previous version of ASM I could run the code without any problem